# new Date() .getTime() not displaying in html <p> </p> NAN error

Tags: javascript

This works:

```
document.getElementById("2").innerHTML =  new Date().getTime() - startDelay ;

var startDelay; //global scope
startDelay = new Date().getTime(); //this is done inside of a function
```

this also works

```
document.getElementById("2").innerHTML = startDelay + " " + startTime ;
var startTime; //global scope
startTime = new Date().getTime(); //this is done in another function

//For some odd reason this does NOT work :/

document.getElementById("2").innerHTML =  new Date().getTime() - startDelay + " " + new Date().getTime() - startTime;
```

Running this in chrome: This gives me a single NAN

```
document.getElementById("2").innerHTML = 1 + " " + new Date().getTime() - startTime;
```

This also gives me a NAN error!

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, but I think @John Vandivier just solved this!

Comment: Great! Please accept the answer by clicking the check mark to the left if it solved your issue.

Comment: Was waiting for the stupid 10 min "cool down thing"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are mixing data types. Try using parens to ensure the math operations complete before the data coerces to string:

```
(new Date().getTime() - startDelay) + " " + (new Date().getTime() - startTime);
```

`NaN` error means "Not a number." It is a type error because JS engine thinks you are trying to "subtract strings" which isn't a valid operation.

Answer (score 5):

whole expression `new Date().getTime() - startDelay + " " + new Date().getTime() - startTime;`

It starts with

```
new Date().getTime() - startDelay
```

which, given startDelay definition, is the same as

```
new Date().getTime() - new Date().getTime();
```

This will give you a number. When you add the number, you try to add a string with a space, in this part of the code:

```
.. - startDelay + " "
```

Now the expression becomes a string. Since your string ends with an empty space, when you add this

```
.. + new Date().getTime()
```

You get something like this

```
"1489700484842 1489700484842"
```

You can tell there's an empty space in the middle.

To that string, if  you do `- startTime;` sure you won't get a number

Comment: Thank you for the in depth  explanation of your answer. It all makes sense now ! :)

Comment: @DR.Palson_PH.d sure, remember to upvote the answers that were useful to you and pick the best answer as correct

Comment: I was tempted to pick this as the answer, but the other guy answered first. But still Thank you!